# Kendogrid population

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'm new to all this kendo stuff i need help in populating kendogrid from a csv file.
The csv data is stored in an array of strings returned by a service.

Data looks like :

0: "Module,LogLevel,LogType,LoggedTime,LogMessage"

1: "00D02D5A4B66 ,CommServer ,Level3 ,Information ,03/16/2015 00:32:57:5716 ,[ISOMMessageHandler::Initialize]-[EventCount:20,ObjectRetryCount:6]"

2: "00D02D5A4B66 ,CommServer ,Level1 ,Information ,03/16/2015 00:32:57:5716 ,ISOMProtocolHandler::HandleConnectGeneric] - Before UpdatePanelTouched - CommServerID : 1, ConnectionMode : 2"

3: "00D02D5A4B66 ,CommServer ,Level4 ,Information ,03/16/2015 00:32:57:5716 ,[PanelDataConfigurationHandler : UpdatePanelConnectionStatus] : CommServerID 1, CommMode : 2"

i need to display 0th indexed data as title of the columns 
and rest in cells of the column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

needed wrapper as told by Thomas.
here is my wrapper function

```
function csvJSON(lines) {

        var result = [];

        var headers = lines[0].split(",");
        headers.unshift("MAC");
        for (var i = 1; i < lines.length; i++) {

            var obj = {};
            var currentline = lines[i].split(",");

            for (var j = 0; j < headers.length; j++) {
                obj[headers[j]] = currentline[j];
            }

            result.push(obj);

        }

        return result; 

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

My advice is to make a wrapper method yourself and get it into JSON.